# cursor.rowcount always -1 in sqlite3 in python3k

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to get the `rowcount` of a `sqlite3` `cursor` in my Python3k program, but I am puzzled, as the `rowcount` is always `-1`, despite what Python3 docs say (actually it is contradictory, it should be `None`). Even after fetching all the rows, `rowcount` stays at `-1`. Is it a `sqlite3` bug? I have already checked if there are rows in the table.

I can get around this checking if a `fetchone()` returns something different than `None`, but I thought this issue would be nice to discuss.

Thanks.

Comment: "actually it is contradictory..." Please provide a reference or a link for this.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3.Cursor

Maybe I got it wrong but the last paragraph of Cursor.rowcount says "This includes SELECT statements because we cannot determine the number of rows a query produced until all rows were fetched." So I guessed that after fetching them witch fetchone() or fetchall() I would get an updated rowcount.

thanks

Comment: When using the package `mysql.connector` the rowcount attribute is -1 after an .execute call of a SELECT-statement, but after the fetchall() call the actual number of rows in the `fetch`ed data is returned. Just an observation...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount):

> As required by the Python DB API Spec,
>   the rowcount attribute “is -1 in case
>   no executeXX() has been performed on
>   the cursor or the rowcount of the last
>   operation is not determinable by the
>   interface”.
>
> **This includes `SELECT` statements
>   because we cannot determine the number
>   of rows a query produced until all
>   rows were fetched.**

That means **all** `SELECT` statements **won't have a `rowcount`**. The behaviour you're observing is documented.

**EDIT:** Documentation doesn't say anywhere that `rowcount` **will** be updated after you do a `fetchall()` so it is just wrong to assume that.

Answer (score 23):

```
cursor = newdb.execute('select * from mydb;')
print len(cursor.fetchall())
```

The fetchall() will return a list of the rows returned from the select.  Len of that list will give you the rowcount.

Comment: The major caveat of this is - if there is a change that this call would return an excessive amount of rows - you could wind up with memory problems. (This is why execute returns a cursor [Python iterator] rather than returning an explicit list or array). (Though In my particular case, this wasn't a concern.)

Comment: an alternative is `len(list(cursor))`

Comment: Thus without considering another important aspect. Whenever you advance your cursor, the information are no longer accessible. If you really want to get the content and a "row count", you need to save the items into a list (or anywhere else you prefer).

Comment: My solution was to fetch the whole result (yes, not good for memory footprint) and then do a `len()` on it as I would use the fetched result in a `for row in rows:` loop anyway.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of "checking if a fetchone() returns something different than None", I suggest:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foobar')
for row in cursor:
   ...
```

this is `sqlite`-only (not supported in other DB API implementations) but very handy for `sqlite`-specific Python code (*and* fully documented, see http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

Answer (score 9):

May better count the rows this way:

```
 print cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name").fetchone()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent too long trying to find this, if you use this line you would want to use the `.rowcount` it should work for you. I'm using it to check if my statement will return any data.

```
    if (len(cursor.execute(sql).fetchall())) < 1: # checks there will be data by seeing if the length of the list make when getting the data is at least 1
        print("No data gathered from statement") #
    else:
       #RUN CODE HERE
```