# Return the number of affected rows from a MERGE with cx_oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

How can you get the number of affected rows from executing a "MERGE INTO..." sql command within CX_Oracle?
When ever I execute the MERGE SQL on cx_oracle, I get a cursor.rowcount of -1.  Is there a way to get the number of rows affected by the merge?

Comment: Does SQL%ROWCOUNT return what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cx_oracle follows the python DBAPI specification (I presume), this is expected 'behaviour'. The exact same problem was discussed [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839069/cursor-rowcount-always-1-in-sqlite3-in-python3k) before.

Some more links with possible solutions:

- http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=220
- http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:122741200346595110