# How to get result / feedback / rowcount / number of rows affected by MERGE query in python snippet

Tags: python, sql, oracle, merge

I am using cur.rowcount with update query and its working fine.

When I use the same with merge query it returns -1 even though merge query is successfully updating many rows.

```
sql = 'merge blah bla..'
params = 'blah blah'
cursor.execute(sql,params)
print(cursor.rowcount)
```

Python 3.4 Oracle 11g

Comment: just out of curiosity, can you please check with `len(cur.fetchall())` is it returning value?

Comment: @akashkarothiya fetch functions work only with queries returning data rows, even if I attempt that print(len(cur.fetchall())) cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not a query

Answer (score 1):

From the definition http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.rowcount
cur.rowcount return in case of (insert, update and delete statements)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401328/return-the-number-of-affected-rows-from-a-merge-with-cx-oracle

Comment: SQL%ROWCOUNT does not work as you think it might, when used with a `MERGE` statement.