# SQLite3 fetchall not actually fetching all

Tags: python, sqlite

i created a simple table with 4 rows and populated it with data.  when i examine the table in the interpreter, all data is present and correct.  when i run `fetchall()` through the Python code, i only get 2 rows.  what's going on?

here's the table (portSettings):

```sql
portName  portPrefix  portOption  portDeadband
--------  ----------  ----------  ------------
mInput1   min1_       1           0.1
mInput2   min2_       1           0.1
mInput3   min3_       1           0.1
mInput4   min4_       1           0.1
```

here's the [updated] code:

```py
db = sqlite3.connect(dbLocation)
ptr = db.cursor()

query = 'SELECT * FROM portSettings;'
ptr.execute(query)
print(f'whatcha got: {ptr.fetchone()}')

if ptr.fetchone():
    results = ptr.fetchall()
    print(f'--------> {ptr.rowcount} results.  voila! ↓ --------')
    print(results)
```

and here's the results:

```
--------> -1 results.  voila! ↓ --------
[('mInput3', 'min3_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput4', 'min4_', 1, 0.1)]
```

Comment: are you sure your dbLocation was right? looking in the right database?

Comment: I mean, you could've queried one database and ran the python script against another -- basically, I tested your code and got all four rows, so I'm a bit perplexed too

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839069/cursor-rowcount-always-1-in-sqlite3-in-python3k for the reason for `-1`.

Comment: Are you still making the two`fetchone()`  calls that you mention in the comments to the answer? Because they will consume tow rows, leaving only two for `fetchall()`

Comment: that's what i figured after some farting around.  i was expecting there to be a cursor reset, like in SQL, but it doesn't seem so.  apparently `ptr.close()` is the way to go, creating a new cursor as needed (thx @richyen)

Comment: Oh yeah those two `fetchone()` calls will reduce the number of rows retrieved with `fetchcall()`.  I think the `fetchall()` call is probably best understood as `fetch_remaining()`.  Each `fetchone()` call is basically like popping off the top of a stack

Comment: @richyen yeah.  that's what i figured.  and i was hunting for a way to reset the cursor (like in SQL) but it appears i just close it and open a new one instead.  thank you for confirming that it does increment the position of the pointer. :thumbsup:

Answer (score 0):

Your example only prints the last two rows -- in my testing, I got all four:

```
$ ls -al | grep foo
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff    8192 Oct 13 14:37 foo.db
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff     252 Oct 13 14:38 foo.py

$ cat foo.py 
import sqlite3

dbLocation = 'foo.db'
db = sqlite3.connect(dbLocation)
ptr = db.cursor()

query = 'SELECT * FROM portSettings;'
ptr.execute(query)
results = ptr.fetchall()
print(f'--------> {ptr.rowcount} results.  voila! ↓ --------')
print(results)

$ python3.11 foo.py 
--------> -1 results.  voila! ↓ --------
[('mInput1', 'min1_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput2', 'min2_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput3', 'min3_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput4', 'min4_', 1, 0.1)]
```

Since you are only seeing the last two rows, I can only think of a couple of possibilities:

1. If you have your `sqlite3` interpreter open, maybe you have an un-committed transaction
2. Depending on the value of `dbLocation`, your python app and sqlite3 interpreter may have opened different `.db` files

The `ptr.rowcount` behavior [is documented](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.rowcount).  To change the count, you can use `len(results)`:

```
$ cat foo.py  | grep len
print(f'--------> {len(results)} results.  voila! ↓ --------')

$ python3.11 foo.py 
--------> 4 results.  voila! ↓ --------
[('mInput1', 'min1_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput2', 'min2_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput3', 'min3_', 1, 0.1), ('mInput4', 'min4_', 1, 0.1)]
```

It might be helpful to fix that `ptr.rowcount` and maybe that might help you get some clues as to why you're only seeing 2 rows?

---UPDATE---
Now that you've shared an updated code, those two `fetchone()` calls will reduce the number of rows retrieved with `fetchcall()`. I think the `fetchall()` call is probably best understood as `fetch_remaining()`. Each `fetchone()` call is basically like popping off the top of a stack

Comment: preceding this snippet of code are two `ptr.fetchone()` statements.  would those be the reason?  does this 'pointer' need to be reset?  i saw nothing in the docs to indicate so...

Comment: it's possible that the pointer needs to be reset, but i'm not sure i can give you a definitive answer on that -- would you be able to update your original post with those two `fetchone()` statements?

Comment: how do you reset a pointer??  i've looked through the docs and found nothing on the reset.

Comment: Sorry, I was using your words -- you had asked `does this 'pointer' need to be reset?`  In my understanding, I was imagining that you would `close()` the cursor with something like `prt.close()` and then open a new cursor, thereby 'resetting' the cursor/pointer

Comment: ohhh.... gotcha.